# Datasets of aligned nucleotide sequences

Tags: bioinformatics, sequence-analysis, sequence-alignment

Where can I find some datasets of aligned nucleotide sequences? And what should I assume about the accuracy of the alignments there?

(I would like to use such datasets for training the alignment model I am working on. In particular, to help me get an estimate on some parameters such as the frequency of single nt INDEL at some locations.)

Comment: What do you want to do with this aligned sequences? Test algorithms? Actually your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: I would like to use such a dataset for training, i.e. to help me infer some parameters for the alignment tool I am working on. Thank you for your comment; I will edit my question to clarify.

Comment: I agree with @Chris! do you mean if the alignment itself can be trusted based on the algorithm used or the sequences themselves can be trusted. Are you worried about the semi-conserved sequences being aligned in a variable manner depending on the algorithm used? For different alignment algorithms please see this post (http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20075/what-is-the-state-of-the-art-algorithm-for-multiple-sequence-alignment). I could be totally wrong but multiple alignment and semi-conserved sequences is mostly an issue for AA not nucleotides since they either match or they don't

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Amino Acid alignment wouldn't work for my purpose (I think), because I am trying to infer the probability of a single nt INDEL at a given location.

Comment: So the alignment has to be trusted in the sense that the nucleotide INDELs predicted by the alignment are correct.

Comment: Well.. Indels are read by your sequencer.. There are machine errors and sample prep errors. You have to set up controls in your machine and train your set.. I haven't really understood your question, however.

Comment: I haven't really understood your comment but that is probably because I'm relatively new to this world. What I'm trying to do: A pair of aligned nt sequences can have regions that are conserved, it can also have insertions/deletions. Those insertions/deletions can be of full codons, but there can also be insertions/deletions of single nucleotides (Am I right so far?). My purpose from a dataset of aligned nt sequences is to study those insertions/deletions (and infer parameters based on them for the alignment tool I'm working on).

Comment: @AnasElghafari.. I would suggest that you use some diagram to make your question clear.

Comment: Okay, let's forget about the "goldstandard" and "absolutely correct" business. I edited the question so now I am only asking for the datasets of aligned nt sequences.

Comment: Hey guys, I edited my question into something which -I hope- is clearer. Can you please remove the hold?

Comment: what do you mean by aligned nucleotide sequences: pairwise alignment or MSA?

Comment: pairwise would be enough for my purpose.

Comment: There are some manually curated HIV alignments at [LANL](http://www.hiv.lanl.gov/content/sequence/NEWALIGN/align.html). HIV is quite variable in length so you will find many indels in these alignments.

Answer (score 2):

You can find 46-way multiz alignment from [UCSC genome browser](http://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTracks?db=hg19&position=chr21:33031597-33041570&hgsid=389402211_SFYtjw2KmAIALH2TNU4GijR6BRXA), it is down on comparative genomics part and labelled as "cons 46-way", which is a genome alignment of 46 vertebrate species. You can use data on their genome browser on the site, or get download information [here](http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg19/multiz46way/).

If you are interested in pair-wise alignments, I don't know of any pair-wise alignment database, but in fact you don't need one. You can search for nucleotide sequences from [NCBI nucleotide database](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nucleotide/) and align them using [BLAST on their website](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CCYQFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fblast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov%2FBlast.cgi%3FPAGE_TYPE%3DBlastSearch%26BLAST_SPEC%3Dblast2seq%26LINK_LOC%3Dalign2seq&ei=WhYdVPnyEeq_ygO-poLoCg&usg=AFQjCNHW6Z7VY8iAUn0taVKiKq4rmn9xlw&bvm=bv.75775273,d.bGQ). BLAST is maybe the most common tool for pair-wise alignments and also for database alignment searches, where a single query sequence is searched for matches throughout a database of sequences. If you want to do a large number of alignments, you can download BLAST to your computer to do them faster.